# C addrinfo struct gets corrupted. But heap is still valid

Tags: c, winsock, memory-corruption

I try to create a socket and connect to a remote host. I resolve the remote host from domain with GetAddrInfo. Which works fine. After the call i get a working addrinfo struct with the right values. But in some situations the struct gets corrupted before calling connect().

```
struct addrinfoW sa = { 0 };
ZeroMemory(&sa, sizeof(sa));
lookup_host(host, &sa);

int sock = 0;
sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
if(sock == -1) {
    return -1;
}
HeapValidate(GetProcessHeap(), HEAP_NO_SERIALIZE, NULL);
if(connect(sock, sa->ai_addr, sa->ai_addrlen) < 0) {
    HeapValidate(GetProcessHeap(), HEAP_NO_SERIALIZE, NULL);
#ifdef _DEBUG
    printf("Error: %d\n", GetLastError());
#endif // _DEBUG

    return -2;
}
```

Where lookup_host is defined as:

```
struct addrinfoW hints = { 0 };
struct addrinfoW *res;
int errcode;
ZeroMemory(&hints, sizeof(struct addrinfoW));
//ZeroMemory(res, sizeof(struct addrinfo));
hints.ai_family = PF_UNSPEC;
hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
hints.ai_flags |= AI_CANONNAME;
errcode = GetAddrInfo(host, L"80", &hints, &res);//GetAddrInfoExW(L"google.de", L"80", NS_ALL, NULL, &hints, &res, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);  //GetAddrInfoEX(L"google.de", L"80", &hints, &res);
win_free(mbHost);
if (errcode != 0)
{
    //perror("getaddrinfo");
    return -1;
}
void *ptr = 0;
while (res)
{
    switch (res->ai_family)
    {
    case AF_INET:
        ptr = &((struct sockaddr_in *) res->ai_addr)->sin_addr;
        break;
    case AF_INET6:
        ptr = &((struct sockaddr_in6 *) res->ai_addr)->sin6_addr;
        break;
    }
    CopyMemory(out, res, sizeof(struct addrinfoW));
    break;
    res = res->ai_next;
}
FreeAddrInfo(res);
```

So this works well on my Quad-Core Win10 laptop. But if i add for example a

```
MessageBoxA(NULL, "After sock", "HTTP", MB_ICONWARNING|MB_CANCELTRYCONTINUE | MB_DEFBUTTON2);
```

call before the connect() call and examine the addrinfo struct in debugger it gets corrupted. For example some time i can see that the ai_canonname which should be "google.com" get overwritten with "After Sock". But the heap is still valid after that. 
So i have no idea where to start debugging this. Could it be some other buffer or struct which overflows somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you free all the memory associated with the results before you use it. For example `ai_canonname` is a pointer to a string that is allocated from the heap. The memory containing its bytes is flagged as free for reuse before you exit `lookup_host`. Your `CopyMemory` will copy the pointer but not the bytes it points to.

NB you should post the whole of `lookup_host` including the function definition.

You need to find a way of avoiding the call to `FreeAddrInfo` until after you are done. Either that or do a deeper copy of the `struct` including all the things being pointed to which you will find rapidly turns into a rabbit hole.

The way I would do it is to provide a callback function that is called while inside `lookup_host`

Answer (score 0):

your while (res) is moving the pointer `res` to other nodes other the origibal one each time you execute line `res = res->ai_next;`, but then you call `FreeAddrInfo(res);` at the end with modified pointer, not the one allocated via GetAddrInfo.

Also, although you don't provide the start of the  lookup_host function, but assuming an inout is ptr, you are setting it to the address of sin_addr from the allocated emory, and then freeing the memory at the end of the function, so it may be used by something else.

Answer (score 0):

Your `lookup_host()` is not returning address data back to the caller correctly, not even close.  `addrinfo` contains pointers to data outside of the `addrinfo`.  But you are just copying the `addrinfo` itself to the caller, but none of the data it points at.

Try something more like this instead:

```
int lookup_host(const wchar_t *host, int family, void *sa)
{
    struct addrinfoW hints;
    struct addrinfoW *res, *addr;
    int errcode, addrlen, returnval;
    void *ptr;

    ZeroMemory(&hints, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family = family;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;

    errcode = GetAddrInfoW(host, L"80", &hints, &res);
    //GetAddrInfoExW(host, L"80", NS_ALL, NULL, &hints, &res, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    if (errcode != 0)
    {
        //perror("getaddrinfo");
        return -1;
    }

    returnval = 0;

    for(addr = res; addr != NULL; addr = addr->ai_next)
    {
        switch (addr->ai_family)
        {
            case AF_INET:
                ptr = &((struct sockaddr_in *) addr->ai_addr)->sin_addr;
                addrlen = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
                break;

            case AF_INET6:
                ptr = &((struct sockaddr_in6 *) res->ai_addr)->sin6_addr;
                addrlen = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in6);
                break;

            default:
                continue;
        }

        CopyMemory(sa, ptr, addrlen);
        returnval = 1;
        break;
    }

    FreeAddrInfoW(res);

    return returnval;
}

...

struct sockaddr_in sa;

if (lookup_host(host, AF_INET, &sa) != 1) {
    return -1;
}

SOCKET sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
if (sock == INVALID_SOCKET) {
    return -1;
}

if (connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&sa, sizeof(sa)) < 0) {
    #ifdef _DEBUG
    printf("Error: %d\n", GetLastError());
    #endif // _DEBUG

    closesocket(sock);
    return -2;
}

...
```

Note, however, that the above returns only the first address found.  A hostname can resolve to multiple IPs, and your PC might not have a route to all of them.  So, you should attempt to connect to every address reported until one is successful, eg:

```
int lookup_host(const wchar_t *host, int family, struct addrinfoW **addrs)
{
    struct addrinfoW hints;
    int errcode;

    ZeroMemory(&hints, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family = family;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;

    errcode = GetAddrInfoW(host, L"80", &hints, addrs);
    //GetAddrInfoExW(host, L"80", NS_ALL, NULL, &hints, addrs, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    if (errcode != 0)
    {
        //perror("getaddrinfo");
        return -1;
    }

    return 0;
}

...

struct addrInfoW *res, *addr;

if (lookup_host(host, AF_INET, &res) < 0) { // or AF_INET6, or AF_UNSPEC
    return -1;
}

sock = INVALID_SOCKET;

for(addr = res; addr != NULL; addr = addr->ai_next)
{
    sock = socket(addr->ai_family, addr->ai_socktype, addr->ai_protocol);
    if (sock == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        break;
    }

    if (connect(sock, addr->ai_addr, addr->ai_addrlen) == 0) {
        break;
    }

    #ifdef _DEBUG
    printf("Error: %d\n", GetLastError());
    #endif // _DEBUG

    closesocket(sock);
    sock = INVALID_SOCKET;
}

FreeAddrInfoW(res);

if (sock == INVALID_SOCKET) {
    return -2;
}

...
```